# fluentd splunk-http-eventcollector plugin Bad Request 400 when using format json

Tags: plugins, kubernetes, splunk, fluentd

I am trying to push the logs to splunk from Kubernetes using fluentd as a daemonset.

When I set `format none` and push to splunk it works. But I want to add kubernetes_metadata so I updated to `format json` and added the `kubernetes_metadata` filter.

Then, I get a 400 Bad Request

```
{"text": "Invalid data format", "code": 6, "invalid-event-number": 0 }
```

Here is my fluent.conf file

```
# Ignore fluentd log messages
<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>

<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /fluentd/log/docker-containers.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  format json
  read_from_head true
</source>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
</filter>

<match kubernetes.**>
  @type splunk-http-eventcollector
  server <host>:8088
  protocol https
  verify false
  token ***
  source fluentd-kube-containers
  sourcetype _json
  host "#{ENV['HOSTNAME']}"
  buffer_chunk_limit 700k
  batch_size_limit 1000000
  buffer_type file
  buffer_path /fluentd/log/fluentd-buffer
  flush_interval 10s
</match>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your original question. But can be an answer to the problem you are trying to solve. If you are ok with paid solutions - https://www.outcoldsolutions.com/ we provide a pre-built application for monitoring Kubernetes and also solve the problem of forwarding logs from Kubernetes containers enriched with Kube metadata. Requires few minutes to install.

Comment: _Then, I get a 400 Bad Request_  from whom do you get this 400? from Splunk? If so, are there corresponding errors in the splunk log saying _what_ bad data format it received?

Answer (score 0):

It was me being stupid, my source was not of `json` format, so splunk didn't like it, my assumption that I need to set `format json` on source to get the kubernetes metadata was wrong, so when I set `format none` and added `all_items true` to `splunk-http-eventcollector` it worked.